How to fix Android SDK update site errors
Whenever I run a simple Flutter App on an Android Emulator, my PC just freezes. I checked the console and found that it usually gets stuck at installing profile.
I did some digging and found that I have 2 errors that I think may be related.

The Android Automotive multi-window System Images
Google XR System Images

Both have unknown error, not sure what to do to get those fixed


I figured it out.
So, the errors I shared here have nothing to do with why my PC freezes. The reason it freezes is because I had to enable Hyper-V
To do this:

Open Windows Features
Select Hyper-V (Both Management Tools & Platform should be selected)
Restart PC

Note: I also fixed the errors by updating the Android SDK build Tools
